# Changing date formats in Excel using

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a excel sheet in which a column has date date in the format `"yyyyMMdd"` and I want to format it as `"yyyy/MM/dd"`.

For this I tried to use following line inside macro, but it's converting cell data as "###.....#" instead of changing date format.

```
Sheet1.Range("C3", "C302").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
...
result = "#####...#"
...
```

Can someone tell me why it's happening? Is there any other way for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all the good answers, I will add simple vba solution...

```
Option Explicit
Sub FormatDate()
    Dim xlRng As Range
    Dim xlShtRng As Range

    '//- Date format 20160112
    Set xlShtRng = [A3:A10] '//- or [A3, A6, A10]

    For Each xlRng In xlShtRng
        xlRng.Value = DateSerial(Left(xlRng.Value, 4), Mid(xlRng.Value, 5, 2), Right(xlRng.Value, 2))
        xlRng.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd" '//- 2016/01/12
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If a date/time cell appears full of # signs, it means that the column is too narrow to display the format.

Make the column wider to accommodate the full width of the selected date format.

See this screenshot. Both columns have the same format. Column A is too narrow to show the dates. Column B is wide enough.

[image]

Edit after discussing in chat:

The screen shot you posted in chat is this:
[image]

The "dates" you are referring to are not dates. They are numbers that are way higher than what Excel uses for dates in this millenium.

Excel stores dates as whole numbers, starting as 1 for 1/1/1900. What you show in your screenshot are numbers way higher than Excel dates.

[image]

Your number `20150930` is NOT what Excel considers Sep-30-2015.  For Excel, that date would be the number `42277`, which you can perfectly format as that date.

The reason that your "dates" formatted with your format string come out as ##### is that the numbers are way higher than what Excel can interpret as dates.

You will need to convert your numbers to real Excel dates, which you can do with a simple formula. With your first "date" number in cell A1, you can use the formula

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

to return a value that Excel regards as a true date for Sep-30-2015 in this screenshot:

[image]

So, the reason for all the # signs is that the numbers you are trying to format as dates are too big for dates in Excel's algorithms.

Comment: I tried to increase the width of column. But for all width, it's showing only "#####...###". :(

Comment: What is your custom formatting string? if the formatting string results in an error, the # signs will remain.

Comment: it's showing "yyyy/mm/dd"/ Check as right click on cell -> cell formatoing -> custom. showing "yyyy/mm/dd". But in the same window in sample clause it's showing string "##########...##"

Comment: Post a sample file to a file sharing service and post a link here.

Comment: Are the date numbers positive values? Excel cannot show negative numbers as dates.

Comment: What is the cell value if you format it to "General"?

Comment: In the begining cell format is general. If I change it to date manually, then also it's showing content "###...#"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100442/discussion-between-rushikesh-and-teylyn).

Comment: I added some explanations that will help you see the error of your ways.

Comment: nice documentation too

Answer (score 2):

Please try this..

```
=LEFT(A1,4)&"/"&MID(A1,5,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A1,2)
```