# How to custom change the date format in excel from any format to dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: excel, date, formatting, ms-office

I need to change date from existing format to dd-MM-yyyy in excel .

EDIT : I have seen other formats , but they don't contain - dd-MM-yyyy format .

Comment: Copy the title of your question and google it.

Comment: You might want to read through this to better understand dates / times in Excel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37101358/1153513 This is probably also a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38001028/1153513 Afterwards, please check if these are true dates. If not then you will find in these posts some code to possibly convert them. If these are true dates then you'll find your answer here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e

Comment: This might help - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f7525b14-2039-41b5-8aa9-6ac63fbb8233/change-date-format-in-ms-excel-2013-form-mmddyyyy-to-ddmmyyyy?forum=excel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34741424/4539709

Comment: It does not have dd-MM-yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own Custom Number Format, entering dd-mm-yyyy:

Codes:

- m = 4
- mm = 04
- mmm = Apr
- mmmm = April

[image: Custom Number Format]

Answer (score 0):

click on the cell then click ctrl+1 
choose date then choose the format from type list

Comment: It does not have dd-MM-yyyy format ... Please check