# Convert an Entire Column in Unix Epoch Time into Excel Date (YYYY-MM-DD) form VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, epoch

I have a CSV that has Unix Epoch Time. While there are examples of converting epoch time into date format with formulas, I could not find any VBA example that converted an entire column (size can vary) of epoch times into a `yyyy-mm-dd` form. What I am trying to do in the macro is

```
Sub FormatTimeStamp()  
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
            For Each dateCol In tbl.ListColumns
                If InStr(dateCol.Name, "timestamp") > 0 Then
                    dateCol.DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
                End If
            Next dateCol
        Next tbl
    Next sht 
End Sub
```

1. Get a list of all sheets in the workbook (Except the active sheet)
2. In each sheet, Read the column name which has Epoch Times (Can I refer to a column name in VBA?)
3. Create a New Column next to it with `YYYY-MM-DD` form (How do I create a new column name to the left hand side of the epoch time)
4. For each item in Epoch time, create the `YYYY-MM-DD` form equivalent in its own column

Comment: use left\mid functions see examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/34741424/4539709

Comment: I looked at the example you shared, but it does not have the epoch time to yyyy-mm-dd conversion, rather it has the conversion from yyyymmdd to yyyy/mm/dd. Thanks for the example though

Comment: I don't believe you can convert with just a number format - epoch time right now is roughly 1493016379 and Excel raw version is 42849.69869. You have to do some sort of a calculation per cell and overwrite the epoch time value. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Yeah Robin, I have several worksheets that have a column called "timestamp". This column timestamp has epoch time in it. I need to either  convert epoch time into yyyy-mm-dd and overwrite the epochtime or create a new column for the yyyy-mm-dd next to epoch time. I tried to set it using Number format, but nothing happens when I run the macro

Comment: Try this formula formula  on `B1` formula `=(A1/86400)+25569` assuming `A1` has epoch time, then format the cell to `NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try a couple of methods - the first method needs a new column and inserts the formula to convert epoch time to an Excel date and then applies a format to get 'yyyy-mm-dd'. This way is pretty simple - originally I was converting the new date with `TEXT` function but if you want to apply `NumberFormat` instead then that is the way I left it below un-commented.

The second method reads the column of epoch times from a `Range` to a `Variant` and then does the calculation on the variant array before writing the converted data back to the sheet. With the second method you could use it to either have a new column of data *or* overwrite the original epoch time data.

You'd have to adapt the code below to your circumstances with `ListObjects` etc but the principle would be the same:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Method1()

    Dim rngEpochTimeData As Range

    ' get times
    Set rngEpochTimeData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A11")

    ' set range offset by 1 column with converting formula with RC notation
    ' set as text
    'rngEpochTimeData.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT((RC[-1]/86400)+DATE(1970,1,1),""yyyy-mm-dd"")"

    ' set as date and also set number format
    With rngEpochTimeData.Offset(0, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-1]/86400)+DATE(1970,1,1)"
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    End With

End Sub

Sub Method2()

    Dim rngEpochTimeData As Range
    Dim varTimeData As Variant
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim lngEpochTime As Long

    ' get times
    Set rngEpochTimeData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A11")

    ' set range data to array
    varTimeData = rngEpochTimeData.Value

    ' iterate array and do conversion
    For lngCounter = LBound(varTimeData, 1) To UBound(varTimeData, 1)
        lngEpochTime = varTimeData(lngCounter, 1)
        varTimeData(lngCounter, 1) = CDate((lngEpochTime / 86400) + 25569)
    Next lngCounter

    ' write to range
    With rngEpochTimeData.Offset(0, 2)
        .Value = varTimeData
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
    End With

End Sub
```

Example input and output:

[image]

Comment: Robin, Perfect.. I have now two choices to pick from.. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You need just minor changes in your code. See the explanations in the code comments.

```
Option Explicit 'see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices

Sub FormatTimeStamp()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim newCol As Long

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
            newCol = tbl.ListColumns("timestamp").Range.Column - tbl.ListColumns(1).Range.Column + 1
              'calculate the position of timestamp column whithin the table
              'note: .Column returns the column number relative to the sheet but we need
              '      the column number relative to the table! Therefore we subtract the
              '      column number of the first column of the table and add 1 to
              '      obtain the position of the column relative to the table.

            tbl.ListColumns.Add Position:=newCol
              'add a new column before the timestamp column

            tbl.HeaderRowRange(newCol).Value = "date from timestamp"
              'add a header name for the new column (optional)

            tbl.DataBodyRange(1, newCol).Formula = "=([timestamp]/86400)+DATE(1970,1,1)"
              'calculate the date from the timestamp with a formula
              'note: we only need to fill the first row of a column
              '      the formula gets copied down automatically by Excel
              '      this works only within tables.
              '      In a normal sheet range we would need to loop throug all rows,
              '      to fill in the formula in each cell of the entire column.

            tbl.ListColumns(newCol).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
              'change the cell format of the data range to international date format
        Next tbl
    Next sht
End Sub
```

For more info see [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

---

Alternative:
If you want empty timestamps to be an empty date too, then use this formula instead.

```
=IF([timestamp]<>"",([timestamp]/86400)+DATE(1970,1,1),"")
```

Comment: Super Helpful Peh! Thanks a lot for the details that could help others as well.