# Date from Text format to Date format in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date

I want to change dates from text format to date format (custom) dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm . I have been reading all types of similar questions inside the website but nothing seems to work for me. Even if I apply changes, the date stays in a text format. Is there a way to use the Date function in VBA. Or generally, any ideas about how I can finally make it work. My dates are vlookups from an excel sheet named "TMS", where they are in a text format. The destination sheet is "Tracker". The dates are imported from a website to the "TMS" sheet so I have to perform the change in format automatically inside the excel. My code is provided below. Much appreciated!!

The code below is the fixed code, for which the date format worked, but it does not run the loop for every row, instead it just copy paste the value of the first row to the other rows. In other words, it works perfectly for the first row, but not for the other!

```
Sub Tracker()

 Sheets("TMS").Select
lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("G2:G" & lastrow)
If Not IsEmpty(Range("G2:G" & lastrow)) Then
.value = .Parent.Evaluate("DATE(MID(" & .Address & ",7,4),MID(" & .Address & ",4,2),LEFT(" & .Address & ",2))+RIGHT(" & .Address & ",4)")
End If
End With
Sheets("Tracker").Select
lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow)
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,TMS!B:G,6,FALSE)"
.value = .value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: your dates are most likely stored as text not a number.  Assuming you have a date in B6 try `=istext(b6)`  if it returns true, then you will need to convert it to a serial date which excel uses.  once that is done you can apply your custom format to it and use date functions on it.

Comment: it is a text ! how can I convert it to a serial date?

Comment: Copy the values to an array, delete the content, change cells' format as date, paste the content back from the array, and they are all dates.

Comment: use the built in text to columns is one way and tell the prompt that the column is in a certain date format.  Alternatively you can read through the text with your VBA and strip id down character group by character group to pull the day, then the month then the year and then use a VBA equivalent to the excel formula `date(year, month, day)`

Comment: @Tehscript sorry for being annoying but I really dont know how to do this .. I am really new at vba! can you help me further?

Comment: @ForwardEd well I need to have hours an dminutes too so date function or something similar for vba is not going to work! any more accurate suggestions ?? :)

Comment: there is also `=TIME(hour,minute,seconds)`   so if you can step through the text and grab those values you can then turn around and dumb them into that formula.  And I know there is a formula in VBA that allows you to use excel formulas.  When you do text to column you can use space as a delimiter. Date will wind up in one column and time in the adjacent.  you can then combine the two and do as you need.

Comment: What format does your time come in as?  are there leading zeros for days and month?  what is the separator?  for time is it 12 hour or 24 hour?  is there a leading zero for hours and minutes? without seeing the format of the original text date it hard to say how to convert...at least from my perspective.

Comment: yes sorry for that .. 20/07/2017 01:30 .. that is the format .. its 24 hour system dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

Comment: Not sure but see this link if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/34741424/4539709

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply add to your `With Range("G2:G" & lastrow)` part:

```
.Value = .Parent.Evaluate("DATE(MID(" & .Address & ",7,4),MID(" & .Address & ",4,2),LEFT(" & .Address & ",2))+RIGHT(" & .Address & ",4)")
```

this should change all strings to numerical values in one step :)

**EDIT**
As `Evaluate` does not want to return an array this way, we simply force it via `INDEX`:

```
.Value = .Parent.Evaluate("INDEX(DATE(MID(" & .Address & ",7,4),MID(" & .Address & ",4,2),LEFT(" & .Address & ",2))+RIGHT(" & .Address & ",4),)")
```

Comment: nice one dirk.  if only I could write VBA code as easy as I do excel formulas.  Love the fact that it is a one line fix.

Comment: @ForwardEd I've written it in a cell -> copy to notepad -> replace `A1` with `" & .Address & "` -> just add `.Value = .Parent.Evaluate(...)` and done... (I AM very lazy) :D

Comment: @DirkReichel your trick actually worked well ... however, even if I get the desired format, this order keeps pasting the same value till the last row.. So, instead of having 25 different dates, I have the same date in all 25 cells.

Comment: I am confused... tested it without errors... will run another test as soon as I am home again...

Comment: ok thank you :) just to clarify it again.. it works PERFECTLY for the first date... but, it takes this date and pastes it all the way to the last row instead of applying this for every row separately. So, it does not make the loop for every row. I will post the code as I have it right now in the section where I had my initial code!

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas added an `INDEX` around the formula to force an array.... should work now :)

Comment: @DirkReichel it works like a boss ;) thank you man for everything!! I have been trying for a long time and you gave the solution! thanks again!!!

Comment: O just one last problem.. even though it works fine and pastes everything great to the destination sheet, it converts the dates inside "TMS" sheet to numeric values, while I would prefer them staying as dates! can we fix this?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas In Excel a "date" is a numerical value. Also is time. So do you want it to be a "string" or a "number"?

Comment: well the dates in the TMS sheet are imported from an external source as dates in a text format. We managed to convert these dates from text format to date format in the destination sheet. However, the conversion also altered the dates inside TMS sheet from text format to numeric  (lets say 19/09/2017 13:24 is now something like 41567.324). Is it possible to keep the text format of the dates on the TMS sheet and just have the conversion only for the destination sheet?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas in that case, do the conversation simply for the "tracker" sheet. Do not touch the "TMS" at all and use my line at your ".value = .value" part.

Answer (score 3):

[image: POC]

in the image above, I have illustrated the formulas used to convert from text to their various components then back to a date serial including time.  The format for F2 was set as a custom format to display correctly.

Comment: I believe the OP is having a different issue. Try inserting `'20/08/2017` into a cell, then try changing its format as you have done in your answer. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: my answers was to give him some tools he could use to rewrite his code to reformat his date in text format to a serial date format that he could then use the remainder of his code to reformat to the custom format. as stated in my comments under the initial question, there is a VBA command that can use Excel formulas.  So with out doing all the code writing, I was just supplying portions that may help make the step in the conversion process. @Tehscript

Comment: And I am the bad guy again, giving the short solution :P

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your worksheet is organised but considering the dates are imported to `Sheets("TMS").Range("G2:G" & lastrow)`, and you are not able to change their format by using only `.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"` then you need to get rid of the complete text and paste them as dates.

You should also avoid selecting sheets. Your code should look something similar to this. Please correct the parts if I guess them incorrectly.

```
Sub Tracker()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim arr() As Date
With Sheets("TMS")
    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arr(lastrow) As Date
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        arr(i) = .Range("G" & i).Value
    Next i

    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow).Delete
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        .Range("G" & i) = arr(i)
    Next i
    .Range("G2:G" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
End With
With Sheets("Tracker")
    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,TMS!B:G,6,FALSE)"
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Based on system settings `20/07/2017 01:30` probably can not be interpreted as datetime. Because looking for `mm/dd/yyyy` will return an error if the month is 20. if that happens, no conversation will happen and it will stay a string. To reenter it into the cell may end with the same result (except for dates where month and day can be misread which will end up with wrong dates)... just keep that in mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Sub Tracker()
    Dim vDB, vT, vD
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheets("TMS")
        lastrow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("G2:G" & lastrow)
            vDB = .Value
            If IsDate(vDB(1, 1)) Then
            Else
                For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
                    vT = Split(vDB(i, 1), " ")
                    vD = Split(vT(0), "/")
                    vDB(i, 1) = DateSerial(vD(2), vD(1), vD(0)) + Val(Trim(vT(1)))
                Next i
            End If
            .Value = vDB
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
        End With
    End With
    With Sheets("Tracker")
        lastrow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("AG2:AG" & lastrow)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2,TMS!B:G,6,FALSE)"
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```