# Convert MMM-DD-YYYY text to date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a set of data which only pulls as `MMM-DD-YYYY.` I'd like to convert it to a date (MM/DD/YYYY format) to look it up versus another set of data.

I recorded a macro to simply replace the months with their respective numbers individually but I know there has to be a better way to do this. Below is my

current code:

```
With ws1.Cells
.Replace What:="jan-", Replacement:="01-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="feb-", Replacement:="02-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="mar-", Replacement:="03-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="apr-", Replacement:="04-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="may-", Replacement:="05-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="jun-", Replacement:="06-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="jul-", Replacement:="07-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="aug-", Replacement:="08-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="sep-", Replacement:="09-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="oct-", Replacement:="10-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="nov-", Replacement:="11-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
.Replace What:="dec-", Replacement:="12-", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End With
```

Comment: Create two arrays, one the month names and the other the corresponding numbers, loop through the first array replacing the name from the array with the number from the second.

Comment: Does ```format(datevar, "mm/dd/yyyy")``` not work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34741424/4539709

Answer (score 1):

This will convert your text string into a true date for the active cell:

```
Sub datefix()
    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveCell.Value
    arr = Split(s, "-")
    ActiveCell.Value = arr(1) & " " & arr(0) & " " & arr(2)
End Sub
```

You can format it or loop it to your heart's content.

*(I am using US locale)*

**EDIT#1:**

With your desired format:

```
Sub datefix()
    Dim s As String
    s = ActiveCell.Value
    arr = Split(s, "-")
    ActiveCell.Value = arr(1) & " " & arr(0) & " " & arr(2)
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: This is great! How can I apply this to a whole range or column(s)?