# Convert six digits to date

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to convert a string of six digits to valid date
example:
121200 is for 12 / 12 / 2000
Another example:
140585 is for 14/ 05 / 1985

I can use DateValue function and CDate but the problem for me is how to determine the correct century part .. I mean how to decide if it will be 20 or 19 before the last two number ..
I tried such line

```
Debug.Print Format("140585", "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

But this prints 26/11/2284

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34741424/4539709

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code in the link deals with 8 digits while I need 6 digits.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Format` to add the slashes here, and then use `DateValue`:

```
Debug.Print Format("1405085", "00\/00\/00") '<~ returns 14/05/85
```

Slightly more detailed:

```
Dim textDate as String
textDate = "140585"
textDate = Format(textDate, "00\/00\/00")

Dim realDate as Date
realDate = DateValue(textDate)

Debug.Print realDate  '<~ returns 14/05/1985
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/two-digit-year-numbers) for how Excel handles two digit year numbers and converting to the appropriate century.

Comment: Thanks a lot but this doesn't return 19 or 20 .. and I would like to decide which one of them

Comment: Hence the link - use `DateValue` to convert to a date, and then let Excel handle the logic for you. It will determine a date based on the rules laid out in that article... so you don't have to worry about the century at all.

Comment: If I used IsDate for this as an example `Debug.Print IsDate(Format("290215", "00\/00\/00"))`, it returns True while this date doesn't exist. That is the point I am aiming at.

Comment: It actually is a date. In the Immediate Window: `? DateSerial(2015, 2, 29)` - returns 01/03/2015.

Comment: This returns a different date ..which is 1 March 2015 and not the 29 / 2 / 2015 .. I need to make a check line that the date is invalid

Comment: That is a different question than the one you posted... and will require slightly more validation than `IsDate`, as you can see.

Comment: When I used your code for the example "290215", it returns "15/02/2029 " ..I need to check the date which is the result of the concatenation

Comment: That is Excel applying its own logic and attempting to understand the date... in any case, what is your question exactly? This seems like it's a larger task than the small question you've posted. If it's about validation of user input or potential date input, then yes sounds like you've got some work ahead of you.

Comment: Yes simply it is a validation for the input to make sure it is a date or not ..The input length will be six digits.

Comment: in short, 6 digits is not enough information for complete validation of a date value unless the source guarantees that each digit is in a consistent place. As stated, if this 6 digit string is user input and not coming from an already automated program, it will be quite difficult to get a 100% accurate conversion all the time.

Comment: What if there's additional information to limit the years (minus 100) I mean Year(Date) - 100 and that results in 1920 so the two digits is > 1920 and < 2020